# Host a webserver on an ESP32D that has a hyperlink that triggers an Arduino song through a buzzer

Tags: esp32, web-server, sound

I would like to use my ESP32D to create a wireless access point and host an HTML page that has a hyperlink and a few other things on it that triggers an Arduino song (rickroll), and plays it through a buzzer.

I just need to know how to host the webserver and make the trigger hyperlink work, right now the HTML is set to send "trigger" whenever the link is pressed.

HTML file: https://pastebin.com/sGmPPVYG

Arduino-song: https://github.com/robsoncouto/arduino-songs/blob/master/nevergonnagiveyouup/nevergonnagiveyouup.ino

Comment: Just to be clear the hyperlink is supposed to make the song play

Comment: this might help ... http://www.martyncurrey.com/esp8266-and-the-arduino-ide-part-6-javascript-and-ajax/

Comment: this is more current technology ... https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-websocket-server-arduino/

Comment: Re “_Rick Roll!/a>_”: you mean “Rick Roll!</a>”.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer. I assume you already know how to build a Web
server on you ESP32, and how to react to client requests. If not, there
are tutorials available on the Internet. Here I will specifically
discuss the issue of the hyperlink.

You wrote:

```html
<a href="trigger">Click Here To Trigger The Rick Roll!/a>
```

Not only the closing tag is incorrect (it should be `</a>`), but such a
link is likely not what you want. The semantics of an hyperlink is “go
fetch that resource and display it here, replacing the current page”.
Unless you do have a displayable resource (Web page, image...) on your
server actually named “trigger”, you do not want an hyperlink. You want
a clickable item that may look like an hyperlink and, when clicked,
triggers a request to the server, but without replacing the current
page.

So I would start by replacing the link by a generic container:

```html
<div id="trigger">Click Here To Trigger The Rick Roll!</div>
```

Then, style it like a link. I don't quite like the underlining, but you
can add it if you wish:

```css
#trigger {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Then, within a `<script>` tag, add the desired behavior:

```javascript
window.onload = () => {
    document.getElementById("trigger").onclick = () => {
        fetch("trigger", { method: "POST" });
    };
};
```

When the user clicks on the element, the client will send a “POST”
request to the server for the “trigger” resource, and the server can
react to this by playing the song. You could use a “GET” request
instead, but that would violate the semantics of “GET”, which is to
retrieve a resource from the server, without affecting its state.